# I would explain this function .map ()

Tags: javascript

I have this function that has the .map () and it is functional since the idea is that we return an array with the elements, but I do not understand its operation if you could explain its development I would appreciate it very much

```
var number2 = [10, 20, 30];

function creatList (value) {
    
     const numbers = value.map (object => `The value is $ {object} .`);
     return numbers;
};

console.log (creatList (number2));

Result: // (3) ["The value is 10.", "The value is 20.", "The value is 30."]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Have you read the docs for “map”? There’s very little here to actually explain.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I do not understand how the values are added to the array, I do not understand how the .map () function works, is it like recrusivity?

Comment: I already read the mozilla documentation

Comment: Added to which array? The one returned by “map”? That’s an implementation detail of “map”, but you could always read the source. It’s likely similar to how you’d write it yourself, but could be a native implementation.

Comment: What isn't clear from the documentation? You have an array, you call `map` on it and you supply a function. The function runs against each element and you get a new array out of the results. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pablo -- As mentioned in the comments above the Mozilla docs explain it pretty well.  That being said, I'm going to try and depict it using another function below.

**For Loop**

```
const number2 = [10, 20, 30];
const numbers = [];

for (let x = 0; x < number2.length; x++) {
  numbers.push(`This value is ${number2[x]}`);
};

console.log(numbers);
```

This hopefully helps to depict what map() is doing.  map() is going to move from one item in your array to the next performing some function on each array item.

So, in your sample code what's going on behind the scenes is it starts at index 0.  It's saying, "Okay this value at index 0 is the number 10, I'm going to perform an action now using this value."  In your case, it will take that value and inject it into a string.  Then it adds that new value to index 0 of a new array.  It will then perform the same action on the 2nd item in the array and then the 3rd.  It'll continue for as many items as you have in your array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks men I already understood that it works like a loop, good explanation

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

map function is working like a for loop method. it's mapping each and every value.

```
var number2 = [10, 20, 30];

function creatList (value) {

 const numbers = value.map (object => `The value is $ {object} .`);
 // value is [10,20,30] 10 => 0th index, 20 => 1st index, 30 is => 2nd index and length is 3.so it does 3 times mapping.
 return numbers;
 };

 console.log (creatList (number2));
```

FYI: But using the spread operator is the easiest way to pass an array argument

Comment: thanks i understand it's like recursion, but it would be as mentioned above a native javascript option Thanks men

Comment: @PabloHernandez it's nothing like recursion. It functions more like a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Map is a fairly simple function that takes each value in a list and applies some sort of function to that value. In the case that you provided the function inserts the value into a string. It's a little unclear with the arrow functions that it's using but you can rewrite it as:

```
const numbers = value.map (function (object) {
    return `The value is $ {object} .` // This value is taken for the new list that map constructs
});
```

So as another example of map lets write a function that multiples every value in a list by two.

```
function multListTwo(list) {
    return list.map(value => value * 2); // This is shorthand for (value) => {return value * 2}
}
```